# Usage of class instance in other php files

Tags: php, namespaces, global, require

Let's say, I have an index.php, where i declare:

```
...
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$telegram = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');
...
```

I'd like to use this variable not only in index.php, but in several other files at the same directory.

What should I use in PHP that this variable would have become visible in other files?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is in your question: *require()*

Comment: [Variable scope in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) + require as Rizier said

Comment: It already is. @Rizier123 why would you use require? It's already available in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose any one from [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), on the page you need this code, and you might need to call `global $telegram;`

Also there is a possibility that your variable can be overwritten by mistake.

There is a Much better approach, you can create a [singleton](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton) class, and get instance where ever you need.

why [Singleton](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton)? Because (assuming), You like to call the same instance overall your project.

```
class Telegram
{

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance($newInstance = false)
    {

        if ($newInstance || null === self::$instance) {
            return self::$instance = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');
        } else {
            return self::$instance
        }
    }
}

$telegram = Telegram::getInstance(); // First Time, will get you new Instance
$telegram2 = Telegram::getInstance(); // Second Time, will get you the instance first time
$telegram3 = Telegram::getInstance(true); // Third Time, will get you the new instance, why? because we passed true as parameter
```

Comment: The only question: how to get instance of new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck') in my case, using Singleton? Because, when we use Singleton pattern, we're instantiating the same Singleton class, not other class.

Comment: you need to create a another method like `getNewInstance` which would not check the existence of `$instance` and blindly create a new one or can pass an optional parameter like `Singleton::getInstance(true);`